# Besides Jamaica, are there other countries where a "Labour" (or Workers' etc.) party is actually right-wing/conservative?

Tags: parties, comparative-politics, symbols

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaica_Labour_Party):

> The Jamaica Labour Party (JLP) is one of the two major political parties in Jamaica, the other being the People's National Party (PNP). While its name might suggest that it is a social democratic party (as is the case for "Labour" parties in several other Commonwealth realms such as Australia, New Zealand and the United Kingdom), the JLP is actually a conservative party.

Are there other countries with right-wing/conservative parties that have left-style words in their title like "Labour", Workers' etc.?

---

The point in an answer below about [Communists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism) (conventionally described as "left-wing to far-left") being 'conservative' in the immediate aftermath of the post-Soviet space is somewhat interesting, but I'm more interested in the conventional sense of ['right-wing'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-wing_politics) and likewise for ['conservative'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism).

For example, the JLP "believes in a market-driven economy and individual personal responsibility" and "illegality of homosexual acts by citing Christian values and the integrity of the family". True, Stalinism also made homosexual acts illegal, but let's not get into that.

Comment: Are you asking about a formal position or the actual position? I am asking because most of the socialist parties in Europe on paper claim to be center-left often they implement right wing policies. The most recent example are the tax breaks proposed by the German government, but in the past there are a lot of example of socialist parties introducing new types of temporary contracts and other tricks to weaken workers rights.

Comment: Are you talking about economically right-wing parties, or socially-conservative (anti-LGBT, anti-feminist, anti-abortion) parties with leftist/socialist economic policies? it's really 2 separate questions.

Comment: @StuartF: I'm most interested in parties that combine them and [still] label themselves as Labor etc. As I mentioned, some Stalinist parties were also socially conservative in some way [homosexuality etc.], but that observation alone isn't very satisfying (let alone new to me).

Comment: Is this question about economical right/left? Or about what is now presented as ideological right/left, which is both separate from the economical one, and highly shifting. For example in the 1848 revolutions, nationalism, ethnostates, and nationality-based separatism was a left-wing concept, while a melting pot multi-ethnic centrally controlled empire was a conservative position.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned National Socialist German Workers' Party yet. Amazing.

Answer (score 20):

Up until very recently, the [Brazilian Labour Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Labour_Party_(1981)) would have fit these criteria; despite the name suggesting a left-wing ideology, the party pivoted right in recent years. In November 2023, it merged with Patriota to form the new Democratic Renewal Party.

In the Czech Republic, there's the [Worker's Party of Social Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workers%27_Party_of_Social_Justice), which is a continuation of the banned Worker's Party. Among their policies are withdrawal from NATO and the EU, reinstatement of the death penalty, and criminalising homosexuality.

Answer (score 12):

In Portugal, the [PSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_(Portugal)) (Partido Social Democrata, Social Democratic Party) is the main centre-right party, with 77 seats in the current Portuguese parliament. The main centre-left party is just the [PS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_Party_(Portugal)) (Partido Socialista, Socialist Party), with 120 seats.

Answer (score 11):

In early Russian Federation (and some would say to this day), Communist Party was conservative/Right Wing because other political forces were taking the progressivist / reformist / economic liberal positions on the spectrum and the Communist Party agenda was keeping whatever is left of Communist economy and social policy, and defending industrial sector of the economy. Their social base was Russian version of "rust belt" (Middle Volga region) - places like that are strongly conservative in other countries.

Comment: Meh, this is actually an example where conservative means left-wing. The same goes for all the Soviet-sphere states in that transition period. But this is relative to who was in power previously rather than [ideology on the usual scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism).

Comment: ""rust belt" (Middle Volga region) - places like that are strongly conservative *in other countries*" -- doubtful how strongly they are 'conservative' and in what sense of that word, besides not wanting job losses.

Comment: @Fizz When everybody else is more economic liberal / globalist, you end up right-ish.

Comment: Fair enough, although Wikipedia claims that protectionism is more a characteristic  of the left than of the right, but  I'm not totally convinced about that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectionism#:~:text=Protectionism%20is%20advocated%20mainly%20by,parties%20generally%20support%20free%20trade. More recently it's chucked to populism https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0032321717723505

Comment: OTOH that paper (on the Dutch electorate) notes "Opposing trade openness is a more substantial driver of voting for a rightist populist party than for a leftist one." So [in part] that's why I'm not so convinced.

Answer (score 11):

Spain's [*Frente Obrero* (literally: "Workers' Front")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workers%27_Front_(Spain)) fits the description, at least when it comes to social matters:

> Despite being strongly connected with the PML(RC) and supporting
> far-left ideologies such as Marxism-Leninism, the FO is not explicitly
> communist. Their political ideology is a syncretic combination of
> left-wing economic positions and **right-wing social viewpoints**.
>
> In their program *A Spain for the Workers*, **they defend national
> sovereignty, Hispanic identity**, free university education, the
> nationalization of strategic economic sectors, energy sovereignty,
> nuclear energy, increasing the minimum wage, supporting the rural
> sector, promoting birth rates, creating more public housing,
> introducing rent control **and limiting immigration**.
>
> **They oppose** capitalism, the European Union, NATO, surrogacy, **feminism**,
> deindustrialization, **queer ideology, the Trans Law, positive
> discrimination, islamization**, cosmopolitanism and political
> correctness.

(Emphasis mine on policies commonly associated with right-wing parties.)

Comment: While a valid answer, this is a bit of a different phenomenon to the JLP. The JLP drifted from centre left to centre right. Parties like FO are a bit more complicated. You could describe them as trying to recreate white-working class 'brocialism' of the 30s to 50s, before feminism, antiracism etc was a major factor in progressive movements, or as fig leaves for hard-right culture warriors.

Answer (score 8):

The Danish party [Venstre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venstre_(Denmark)) (literally "the Left") started out as a left-wing party, but by now is considered center-right.

Comment: To add to the confusion: [Radikale Venstre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Social_Liberal_Party) (literally "the Radical Left") who are considered centre/centre-left.

Answer (score 5):

At the European parliament there is the center-right [European People's Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_People%27s_Party), and one of its Spanish members is Partido Popular (People's Party).

Comment: Yeah, but 'people' is semantically a bit broader than 'workers/labour'. Albeit most people work... OTOH some communist parties [have](https://ecfr.eu/special/mapping_palestinian_politics/palestinian_peoples_party/)  "people's" in their name too.

Comment: @Fizz yes, I was aiming at its association to communist countries, as the question seems to allow for some leeway.

Comment: a party named "People's Party" usually is a or *the* major conservative party in Europe. It does not indicate being left-wing at all.

Comment: @Chieron that's so strange to an old Cold Warrior like me, who remembers People's Liberation parties.

Answer (score 4):

[The Cambodian People's Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambodian_People%27s_Party) - I know it's 'People's' and not Labour or Worker, but it started out as a dictatorial Communist Party - as in 'people's republic' - and is now a dictatorial conservative party. So 'People's' was not being used in the same sense as the Spanish 'People's Party', but the two parties are now on the same side of the left-right divide.

Unlike other ruling communistic parties, like the Chinese Communist Party or the Communist Party of Vietnam, which still claim to follow some form of Marxism, the Cambodian People's Party officially disavowed Marxism in 1991.

Comment: Since Cambodia is very close to China is almost every regard, I suspect their ideology mirrored the changes in the CCP, but I know very little about ideology in Cambodia in particular, these days.

Answer (score 1):

The [Liberal Party of Australia](https://www.liberal.org.au/) is a right-wing party.

Comment: But outside of the US, *liberal* is not a "left-style word".

Comment: The [Liberal Party of Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Party_of_Australia), founded in 1944, was never a worker's party. At it's most "left" it was center right party, representing "middle Australia" with policies supporting small businesses. The worker's party in Australia has been the [Australian Labor Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Labor_Party), founded in 1891. It is the oldest political party in Australia.